# Can't open pictures with EnableRaisingEvents

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any reason why I can't seem to open pictures using the following code?

```
   var process= System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(DownloadDirectory + "/GedDocuments/" + fullName);
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                process.Exited += new EventHandler(closedProgram);
```

.CSV, .docx, .pdfs are opening just fine. However, when I try to open some pics with EnableRaisingEvents, the following error (in the second line of code) is being returned:

System.NullReferenceException

Process was **null**

Comment: Have you verified that the path to the image is correct?

Comment: It is. It opens just fine if EnableRaisingEvents is set to false.

Comment: Do not use the static `Start` method.  Create a new `Process` instance, set the properties, and then call `Start` on that instance.